# What is the correct way to use wildcard DNS?

Tags: apache, subdomain, wildcard, virtualhost

**I need the apache virtualhost follow the following rule:**

1- If domain.com or www.domain.com then show contents in /var/www/domain.com/home

2- If blog.domain.com then show contents in /var/www/domain.com/blog

3- If is a wildcard(*) then show contents in /var/www/domain.com/platform

**To make this possible I edited my virtualhost as follows:**

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/home

ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias blog.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/blog

ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/plataforma
```

**DNS ZONE:**

@ IN A 111.111.1.111

(*) CNAME @

Doubt:

**The way I did is a good practice? If not, how about it? Do I need to create a record in the DNS zone for the `www` and `blog`?**

Comment: You cannot have multiple `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` on the same `virtualhost`. You can however have multiple address *separated by a space* on the `ServerAlias` for example `ServerAlias www.domain.com *.domain.com`. If you point all of it to your document root, you can easily redirect the domains using `.htaccess`.

Comment: Sorry. Each is within a different VirtualHost. I just copy and past without the <VirtualHost>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a record in your DNS as long as you have a *.domain.tld entry that points to the correct server and as long as all 3 websites are running on the same host. if at one point you want to move on and migrate one of these website to a different server you will have to add this particular subdomain to the DNS.

I think overall this is not a very bad setup but i am unsure if the ServerName value for the second and third website should be different from the first one. May you should use the Alias as ServerName and get totally rid of the Alias in the second and third entry.

Comment: Apache returns the following error in third entry with the suggestion you gave me: "Invalid ServerName *.domain.com, use ServerAlias to set multiple server names."

Comment: i was more thinking about something like this: 
    ServerName blog.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/blog

    ServerName plataforma.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/plataforma